# How to extract strings in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 1000+ rows and 37 columns and would like to drop the first word from the string including the underscore and keep remainder of the string:
example

```
    Column A                                    Column B       Column C
Mid-size colourblind_RED_Pglasses_Vision           xxx         xxx
High-size cannotEat_JAM_Pots_Jammie                yyy         yyy
```

I want to drop the first word from the string including the underscore and keep remainder of the string for column A eg. RED_Pglasses_Vision.

Comment: So, do you want to have string to be "colourblind RED Pglasses Vision" without underscores after dropping "Mid-size"?

Comment: Hi; @Mohanasundaram I want the string to be: RED_Pglasses_Vision

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaround:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=_).*")
```

where `x` is you vector with the strings and `(?<=_)`is lookbehind asserting that the match must start after the first underscore

Answer (score 0):

We could use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(str1, whitespace = "[^_]+_")
[1] "RED_Pglasses_Vision" "JAM_Pots_Jammie"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- c("Mid-size colourblind_RED_Pglasses_Vision", "High-size cannotEat_JAM_Pots_Jammie")
```